# Constructing list in globalMap and retrieving it as flow

Tags: talend

I have 3 levels of folders and I am using them as below:

```
tFileList_1 --iterate--> tFileList_2 --iterate--> tFileList_3 --> tJava ...
```

And tJava has multiple branches after it.

Based on certain conditions which are written in tJava (as seen above) and also other tJava (not seen above, but present in multiple branches), I want to collect list of files that satisfy particular condition.

So, I am thinking of putting them to globalMap like below:

```
Initialise:
List<String> filesMetCondition = new ArrayList<String>();  
globalMap.put("filesMetCondition", filesMetCondition);

Putting into array: (from multiple places)
((List<String>)globalMap.get("filesMetCondition")).add("file2");
```

Populating globalMap should not be a problem. 
My question is how to access this globalMap as a flow. I should be able to use something like tHashOutput or tFixedFlow or tForEach that links to above globalMap variable so that I can connect components to it.

Comment: Are you writing values to globalMap from multiple places at the same time? It is write synchronized so you might lose data. Contexts are better in this way. Consider using a routine because that is independent of the job so multiple jobs can see it, and you can have nice accessors to it, like myRoutine.addFile() myRoutine.getFiles(filter). Also take a look at tJavaFlex that allows you to create your own for each loop

Comment: For this scenario, although it is writing to globalMap from multiple places, it is still on single thread so it is not a problem. I like your idea of using routine and getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used a `tLoop` to iterate your ArrayList stored in the globalMap.

[image]

[image]

then you can access the current value with

```
String value = 
     ((List<String>)globalMap.get("filesMetCondition")).
          get(((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE")));

System.out.println(value);
```

To use the value in a Flow, add a `tIterateToFlow`

[image]

[image]